# Check how long ago an application was ran

Tags: python-3.x, windows, date

I want to check with a python program the date of the time a specific program was ran
for example I didn't open Chrome for 2 days I want it to say the date 2 days ago...
Is that possible?

(I'm using windows)

Comment: Is this for a python program you are making or just any programs in general?

Comment: I'm making a python program